# Power of transcendental number.

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers

There are some results that i found

$1.$ if $a$ is an algebraic number other than $0$ and $1$ and $b$ is irrational algebraic then $a^{b}$ is transcendental like $2^{\sqrt{5}},3^{\sqrt{7}}$etc.

$2.$ $e^{a}$ is transcendental for algebraic number $a.$

Now i am searching other results like $(b)^{b}$ where $b$ is transcendental. Is it algebraic or transcendental? like $\pi^{\pi},e^{e}$etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [possibly transcendental numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Possibly_transcendental_numbers).

Comment: re 2. $e^a$ is transcendental for non-zero algebraic $a$....$e^0=1$.

Comment: This is a surprisingly difficult subject.  Easy enough to understand the questions but far from easy to answer them.  As Klangen says, we don't even know that $e^e$ is irrational though I would not expect anyone to place a bet on it being rational or algebraic.

Answer (score 1):

The set of algebraic numbers is countable but the set of transcendental reals is uncountable. And any real interval of positive length is an uncountable set . It follows that $b^b$ is transcendental for "almost all"  transcendental $b$, that is, for all but countably many $b$. I don't know whether the status of $b^b$ is known for any specific cases. And if there is a good abbreviation for "transcendental" my fingers will be grateful.The results you quoted :1. is called the Gel'fond Theorem.And 2.( for $a\ne 0$) is a special case of the Hermite-Lindeman Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Currently we do not even have the tools to check whether a $b^b$, where $b$ is a transcendental number, is irrational. For instance, it might be that $e^e$ *is rational*.